# HTTP request outside setInterval is executed for every setInterval iteration when using @pinia/nuxt

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

I am trying to build a timer using @pinia/nuxt with nuxt 3. I also want to make an http request when the timer is started to sync my db.

The problem I am facing is that whenever I call the action `start`, the http request is made for each iteration of `setInterval` and I only want to run it once.

This is the pinia module. I am calling the `start` action from an `onClick` event in a component.

```
state: () => ({
  timer: {
    id: null,
    isRunning: false,
    time: 5,
    timer: 0,
    state: null,
  } as Timer,
}),
actions: {
  start() {
    this.timer.isRunning = true
    this.syncTimer()
    if (!this.timer.timer) {
      this.timer.timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.timer.time > 0) {
          this.timer.time--
        } else {
          clearInterval(this.timer.timer)
          this.reset()
        }
      }, 1000)
    }
  },
  stop() {
    this.timer.isRunning = false
    clearInterval(this.timer.timer)
    this.timer.timer = 0
  },
  reset() {
    this.stop()
    this.timer.time = 1500
  },
  syncTimer() {
    backendAPI<Timer>('/api/timer', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: this.timer
    }).then(({ error, data }) => {
      if (!error.value) {
        const id = data.value?.id ?? ""
        this.timer.id = id
        this.timer.state = "created"
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Custom fetch composable `backendAPI.ts`:

```
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user'
import { defu } from 'defu'

export function backendAPI<T>(url: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  const { token } = useUserStore();
  const appToken = useRuntimeConfig().public.appToken

  const defaults: UseFetchOptions<T> = {
    baseURL: config.public.baseURL ?? 'http://localhost:4000',
    key: url,
    params: {
      token: appToken
    },

    headers: token
      ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      : {},
  }

  const params = defu(options, defaults)

  return useFetch(url, params)
}
```

Comment: why using timer to update data? if you want to be realtime, sulotion is about web sockets.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that would be the perfect solution and I will probably implement it in the future but for the moment I would like to understand this behaviour to keep it simple if possible.

Comment: The description is not clear. "he http request is made for each iteration of the setInterval loop" - which loop? If you mean it's made every second then it's not possible in the code you posted, unless you call syncTimer or start constantly somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the nuxt 3 `useFetch` function.

From the [nuxt documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch):

> All fetch options can be given a computed or ref value. These will be watched and new requests made automatically with any new values if they are updated.

So every time the timer value is updated, `useFecth` will automatically make a new request.

Adding `watch: false`  to the request solved my problem

```
backendAPI<Timer>('/api/timer', {
  method: 'POST',
  watch: false,
  body: this.timer
}).then(({ error, data }) => {
  if (!error.value) {
    const id = data.value?.id ?? ""
    this.timer.id = id
    this.timer.state = "created"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the correct way of implementing realtime feature, is to use sockets. But, if you need to do it in a polling style, you can write a guard, something like this:

```
actions: {
  start() {
    if (this.timer.isRunning) return;

    this.timer.isRunning = true;
    this.syncTimer();

    this.timer.timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.timer.time > 0) {
        this.timer.time--;
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.timer.timer);
        this.reset();
      }
    }, 1000);
  },
  // ...
}
```

Hope this helps.